# How to call external method from nested ajax (success) method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, marionette

I need to call **onSuccessLogin** method from ajax **success** method, or put response as argument into  **onSuccessLogin**.
Thank you for answers.

```js
submit: function (form) {

      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/login",
        data: {
          login: $(form).find('#login').val(),
          password: $(form).find('#password').val(),
          deviceType: environmentInfo.browser,
          sdkVersion: environmentInfo.browserVersion,
          osVersion: environmentInfo.OS
        },

        success: function(res) {
          localStorage.setItem("languagesList", res);
          //how to call onSuccessLogin method from here?
        },

     //Another implementation
        // success: this.onSuccessLogin(res), - dosen't work, if I want put response from ajax into this method call

        error: this.onErrorLogin
      });
    },

onSuccessLogin: function () {
  //localStorage.setItem("languagesList", res); get response from second implementation
  window.location = "/";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a reference (that can be seen from the scope of AJAX `success` callback) to the object holding `onSuccessLogin`.

Inside the `submit` method (as a sibling of `onSuccessLogin`) that object is `this`.

Also see MDN reference on [ES6 Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - abstraction for binding `this` to enclosing scope.

```js
submit: function (form) {

      var self = this;
  
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/login",
        data: {
          login: $(form).find('#login').val(),
          password: $(form).find('#password').val(),
          deviceType: environmentInfo.browser,
          sdkVersion: environmentInfo.browserVersion,
          osVersion: environmentInfo.OS
        },

        success: function(res) {
          localStorage.setItem("languagesList", res);
          self.onSuccessLogin();
        },

     //Another implementation
        // success: this.onSuccessLogin(res), - dosen't work, if I want put response from ajax into this method call

        error: this.onErrorLogin
      });
    },

onSuccessLogin: function () {
  //localStorage.setItem("languagesList", res); get response from second implementation
  window.location = "/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this logic is correct or not , if you place the function outside of ajax loop it will work  .

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test',
    success: function(data) {
    alert("received contents="+data);
    onSuccessLogin();

}  

}); 

 function onSuccessLogin() {
        alert("Successfully logged!!!");
        }
```

Comment: previos solution works fine for me, but thank you for answer!)